React Native: Pressable Needs to be Pressed Twice (First Press Dismisses Keyboard)
I am aware this looks like a repeat question, but I've tried all solutions to previous questions similar to mine!
This post describes the issue well: Touchable Opacity Requires Two Taps to Submit When Keyboard Open - Passing keyboardShouldPersistTaps to ScrollView Does Not Work - Fresh Out Of Ideas
Their solution was this:

In my case, the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop had to go not on the
next higher level component, but rather the highest level component
that the user interacts with. For me, this was a SectionList, within
each TextInput was rendered.

I don't completely understand it, but regardless, I've tried wrapping every component from the root all the way down to the Pressable in a ScrollView with keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always". I've also tried replacing this with handled. I've also tried replacing the Pressable with TouchableOpacity and TouchableWithoutFeedback. I've also tried adding the keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop to every component from the root to the Pressable, ScrollView or not.

can you please explain what happen and what need to happen in your scenario?

If you look at the other question I linked, I am running into the same problem as them.

okay! so you need to make button press works at once not twice when keyboard is active right?

yes! that's right

you can try this
`
..your code here
`
let me know if it works!

thank you for your suggestion! I tried wrapping every element from the modal all the way down to the pressable in a scrollview with keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never", but it didn't work
